# Is it possible to chain event listeners in Android?

Tags: android, event-listener

I have an activity which contains QuickContactBadges. I'm looking for a way to either chain event listeners on the QuickContactBadge, or to call the default listener from within an override.

Specifically, what I am looking to do is have the QuickContactBadge, when clicked to show the QuickContact card, and then to `setResult` and `finish`, to close my activity.

So either I want to add a **second** listener to the badge in addition to the default one, or implement something like the following:

```
bdg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        QuickContactBadge bdg = (QuickContactBadge) view;
        bdg.base.onClick();  // PSEUDO-CODE LINE
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, null);
        finish();
    }
});
```

Are either of these methods possible, or is there some other way I should be doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer to what I was trying to do was not actually in an event listener at all.

The key to getting my activity to close when the QuickBadge is clicked was to add `android:noHistory="true"` to the activity definition in the application manifest file.

Though, it would still be interesting to know yes/no if there ***is*** a way to chain event listeners.